# How to get string values between a regex match?

Tags: regex, assertion, regex-lookarounds

Hi I need to split and get the following fields from a text:

```
08 SET
Paypal *Dibp    370,34
08 SET
IOF de "Paypal *Dibp"   23,63
12 SET
Pagamento recebido  -4.151,76
```

For each of this entries I needed to extract:

(day month) (Description of transaction) (+ or + Numeric value)

I tried[1] with a lookahead assertion regex, seeking for the ',' but, then I don't know how to look back and match the number.

[1] ^(\d\d\s.*)\n(.*)(?=,)(?<=)

Comment: `(\d+\s*\w+)\n([^+\-\d]+)([\d.,\-+]+)` [Click here](https://regex101.com/r/POGBTs/1)

Comment: This will fail if I have a Description which has any number. For example:
13 SET
The 7up store  -22.34

Comment: How about this then? `(\d+\s*\w+)\s*(.*?)([\d.,\-+]+(?=$))` [Link](https://regex101.com/r/POGBTs/3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a good start there. I think you can actually match it all without using lookaheads with this:

```
^(\d\d \w+)\n(.*)\s+(-?[\d,\.]+)$
```

- `\d\d \w+` in the first set of parens will match the day and month.
- `.*` in the second set of parens will match the description.
- The `\s+` will match the spaces between the description and the amount.
- `-?[\d,\.]+` will match a positive or negative amount.
- `$` matches the end of a line.

With this expression, your day and month will be in `$1`, the description in `$2`, and the amount in `$3`.

Comment: This works as magic!! Thanks, works better than the one I end up figuring out later.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got to something that is solving my problem. Not a bit elegant but, seems its working:

```
^(\d\d\s.*)\n(.*)(\s-{0,1}\d{1,3}[,.]\d{2,3},{0,1}\d{0,2})
```